# How to use RxJS, MySQL and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable

I need a with RxJS for MySQL in NodeJS. Could someone give me an example for one select?

On front-end I will use Angular2.

Comment: You probably find something by googling! Your question doesn't show you looked before asking. I advise reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried but did not find anything useful or some example that would show me how to do it! If I would find i would not post here a queston...

Comment: Why do you want to use Rxjs?

Comment: @J.Chomel as I would like to learn it :) Nothing more :)
Angular2 somehow push it and that is why I would like to try it on Nodejs side.

Comment: So if you want to use it, there must be a tutorial that you try to follow. Give us more or this will look to broad a question.

Comment: Google is your friend. Thinking by yourself too. This is not the place where people help you learn things. You learn those things and when you have specific questions, you come and ask, showing what you tried, code sample, and the result of your previous research. There are a ton of tutorial with RxJs, a ton on mySQL, a ton on Angular2 with Rxjs, so you have more than enough resources to write some code and experiment, and see how it goes. If your goal is learning, that's the best way.

Comment: @MihaZoubek I to am trying to find tutorials on this exact stack minus angular. Please share any tutorials you found since asking!

Comment: Unbelievable that such a question gets 4 upvotes, with such a wealth of info available on SO and on the Internet. I mean, its like 10 of encyclopedias full of it. And yes, 3 yrs after asking im still shocked :p

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using the [MySQL](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/) npm package in a desktop application made with [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) and [Angular](https://angular.io/).

However the same should work even on a plain NodeJS application by installing and importing [rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs).

---

I've first installed `mysql` and `@types/mysql` package with:

```sh
npm install --saved-dev mysql @types/mysql
```

Then I've created a MySQL service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Connection, ConnectionConfig, FieldInfo, MysqlError } from 'mysql';

const mysql = require('mysql');

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MysqlService {

  private connection: Connection;

  constructor() { }

  createConnection(config: ConnectionConfig) {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
  }

  query(queryString: string, values?: string[]): Observable<{results?: Object[], fields?: FieldInfo[]}> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.connection.query(queryString, values, (err: MysqlError, results?: Object[], fields?: FieldInfo[]) => {
        if (err) {
          observer.error(err);
        } else {
          observer.next({ results, fields });
        }
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Now I can use my `MysqlService` in any other service or component to connect to the mysql database and execute queries.

For example:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MysqlService } from '../../services/mysql.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private mysqlService: MysqlService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mysqlService.createConnection({
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'my_password',
      database: 'my_database',
    });

    this.mysqlService.query(`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = 'Francesco'`).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```