# How to use mysql, rxjs, angular/electron to connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, npm, rxjs

I have an angular/electron/ag-grid app that display information as frontend. I need to hook up the grid to access a mysql server. I was following the following link and created a mysql-service.ts:

[How to use RxJS, MySQL and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639493/how-to-use-rxjs-mysql-and-nodejs?answertab=votes#tab-top)

however, when I install the necessary mysql drivers by :

```
npm install mysql $types/mysql
```

the program always complain about missing references:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'c:\ts3\node_modules\mysql\lib' ERROR
>   in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Auth.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'c:\ts3\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   'c:\ts3\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'net' in 'c:\ts3\node_modules\mysql\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'stream' in 'c:\ts3\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in
>   'c:\ts3\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'tls' in 'c:\ts3\node_modules\mysql\lib'

I mugged around the main.js and html page to refer those reference to null or empty. However, by doing that the `mysql-service` would do nothing when calling to connect to server. Please help me to connect my code to a mysql server

Comment: `$types/mysql` only installs typescript type definitions for the mysql node package. If you want to install the mysql drivers, you need to run `npm install mysql`

Comment: i did install both: npm install mysql $types/mysql

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087330/angular-6-many-cant-resolve-errors-crypto-fs-http-https-net-path-stream